# Azure table : Fetch without create a specific class or knowing the whole schema

Tags: c#, .net, azure, cloud, azure-table-storage

I have a table "constants" with a specific shema like :
*PartitionKey, RowKey, Timestamp, ARG1, ARG2, ARG3*

for example these entities:
*production, 0, 01/01/2012, L, 5, 7*
*production, 1, 01/01/2012, F, 7, 7*

Can I fetch an entity without create a class ?
Something as:

```cs
var query = MagicFunctionWichGiveAEntity("production", "0"); //0 is the RowKey  
var result = query.ValueOf("ARG1") // result = L
```

I found [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/avkashchauhan/archive/2011/03/28/reading-and-saving-table-storage-entities-without-knowing-the-schema-or-updating-tablestorageentity-schema-at-runtime.aspx) but it look like complicated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to do this is with the **ReadingEntity** event (as described in the post you reference). If you want to see a fully working implementation I suggest you take a look at the **Storage Services Smart Client** located here: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/appfabriccat/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=5474

You'll need to look at the files:

- Client\Helpers\CloudStorageHelper.cs
- Client\Helpers\ConversionHelper.cs
- Client\Helpers\CustomEntity.cs

An alternative solution would be to interact directly with the REST API where you can get an entity in XML format: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dd179421

Comment: Ok, so no very easy way. I am a coward I go use SQLAzure in first time. I will clean my code when I have enough time. I notice that helper class of Storage Services Smart are usefull, thank for the link !

Answer (score 0):

I have written an client that supports dynamic (unspecified) columns by using a dictionary to hold the name/value pairs. It also supports many other features like arrays, enumerations and data larger than 64K.

It is available free for personal use. You can get it at http://www.lucifure.com  or via NuGet.com.